# mySql sort results based on multiple columns values

Tags: mysql, sql

i have below table

| ID | nameA | nameB | NickNameA | NickNameB | viewColm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sundaresh |  | sundar |  | A |
| 2 | altos | Maruthi |  |  | A |
| 3 | anand | Tech | aron | aron | B |
| 4 | gautham | green | adani | port | B |
| 5 | mahindra | Scorpio | XUV |  | A |
| 6 | Tata |  |  |  | A |
| 7 | Narayan | cart | Cysco | Krypto | B |
| 8 | Satya | Soft | oreo | Micro | B |
| 9 | Shiv | give |  | hcl | B |
| 10 | Ratan |  | Indigo | indica | A |

i'm sorting based

```
Select ID, Case when viewColm = 'A' Then nameA ELSE nameB END as name, 
           Case when viewColm = 'A' Then NickNameA ELSE NickNameB END as nickName 
From tablename 
Order by nickName,name
```

view demo : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=0812b63c9024fb2b5b9ae45bbe12351e)

| ID | viewColm | name | nickName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | altos |  |
| 6 | A | Tata |  |
| 3 | B | Tech | aron |
| 9 | B | give | hcl |
| 10 | A | Ratan | Indigo |
| 7 | B | cart | Krypto |
| 8 | B | Soft | Micro |
| 4 | B | green | port |
| 1 | A | sundaresh | sundar |
| 5 | A | mahindra | XUV |

the order i need to sort result is(if we have nickName, nickName to be sorted, if nickname is empty then name column to be sorted alphabetically):

| ID | viewColm | name | nickName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | altos |  |
| 3 | B | Tech | aron |
| 9 | B | give | hcl |
| 10 | A | Ratan | Indigo |
| 8 | B | Soft | Micro |
| 4 | B | green | port |
| 1 | A | sundaresh | sundar |
| 6 | A | Tata |  |
| 5 | A | mahindra | XUV |

Comment: MySQL or SQLite? Which versions? They're different products, with different dialects. In SQLite and MySQL 8 you can use a CTE or subquery. In earlier MySQL versions only subqueries would work

Comment: Store null nicknames as null. Then use COALESCE

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for `nickname = ''` and `order by` as follows:

```
Order by case when nickName = '' then name else nickname end, name
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d2bc932cc2293b7ea64515daad1fd2e4)